# How to redirect a submitted Caldera Form to another page?

Tags: wordpress

I created a form using the Caldera Forms plugin.

When submitted I want it to redirect to another page.

I've set up the Redirect Processor like in the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

However when I submit my form I'm redirected to the current page with an additional parameter at the end.

ie. `http://nsa/wordpress/?page_id=16&cf_id=17`

How can I redirect to another page?

Comment: Your page id must be 55 so in that case only it will redirect to same page.

Comment: I gave up on Caldera and wrote my own script. Thanks for your answer though. It may be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing same issue,  but just use absolution URL  like /?page_id=16

mean don't use  http://example.com   (dont use domain name, just use the Page with "/")

so it could be  /thank-you    or  /page_id=16